# Boxes display differently in Safari

Tags: html

Can anybody explain to me why the two boxes "Badrum" & "Sovrum" get on top of each other in Safari but in all other browsers they lay side by side.

It used to work in Safari but I can't remember any changes I've done that should affect this.

http://linusfrimodig.se/karin/

Comment: Please give you code, describe how it is displayed and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out the cause, however if you change the *flex-flow* property to *nowrap*, it should work (overloading the line 15118 of *flatsome.css*):

```
.row, .gallery {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!
Saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you mentioned, I can only think of 2 scenarios where such a thing can occur. This question is still too vague to answer, and to get more accurate feedback please provide us not only your problem, but also your code and what you have tried so far.

The scenarios are:

1) The `<div>` or whatever content "below" the overlaying div is floated, and there has not been a `clear:` attribute added to the immediate next `<div>`, or is not optimised for the browser which you see the problem in `(-webkit-, -o-, -moz-)`.

2) The margin of the second `<div>` is great enough that it lays side by side the floated `<div>`, or otherwise doesn't get optimised by *that* browser you're using, and ignores the margin and overlays the first `<div>`.

Do provide us some code, anything you've tried, as you've mentioned "It used to work in Safari but I can't remember any changes I've done that should affect this.", which means you have tried something.